# Is there a way to find elements that have a text value less than a variable?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
try:
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='Overflowreact__OverflowContainer-sc-7qr9y8-0 jPSCbX Price--amount']").text() < Snipeprice
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    else:
        print("Snipe found!")
```

This is my current attempt to find the element and then test if the text value is less than the snipe price.
This is the HTML of what I'm trying to check[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvFlu.png).

So basically i want to refresh the website, check for if there is a element that exists below a certain price and then do a certain task or just wait a certain amount and try again.

If there is any more info you need, add a comment, I'm new to coding and Stackoverflow so I don't know everything you would need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you could make your CSS selector a little lighter and change it to `div.Price--amount` (note that the correct way to select by `class` attribute is using `.{class-name}`).

Next thing you probably want, if I understand your problem right, is to select multiple elements and not just the first one. You can achieve this by calling `find_elements` instead of `find_element`.

The last thing is the `.text()` method returns a `str` object and you need to compare it by its numerical (`float`) value. You want to convert it first.

```py
for element in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.Price--amount"):
  try:
    if float(element.text) < Snipeprice:
      print("We've got a match")
  except ValueError:
    print(value, "is not a valid price")
```

Comment: I get the error: if float(element.text()) < Snipeprice:
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Nvm the fix to the code is to do: if float(element.text) < Snipeprice: with the parentheses removed after element.text

Comment: Yes, that's my bad, I didn't check that with Selenium docs. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
f"//div[@class='Price--amount' and number(.) < {Snipeprice}]"
```

I think it would be this for an xpath. No need for loops or anything if you only want to check a single value under.